# Kendo TreeView - Add Delete Image Icon only to Parent Node that have no children

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, treeview, kendo-treeview

So I have a Kendo TreeView in which parent nodes have children node items.

I am really not fond of these templates but I don't know other ways to do the image icon.

This code always shows the image icon, but I only want it is **SHOW** if there is **NOTHING** underneath it.

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    #: item.ReportGroupName #
    # if (!item.hasChildren) { #
         <a href='\#'><span class='delete-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span></a>
    # } #
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a glimpse of my code

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({

                                    transport: {
                                        read: {
                                            url: serviceRoot + "/GetReportGroupAssignments", 
                                            dataType: "json" 
                                        }
                                    },
                                    schema: {
                                        model: {
                                            id: "Id" 
                                            ,
                                            children: "items",
                                            hasChildren: "Id"

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

Then

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                                    expanded: true,
                                    dragAndDrop: true,
                                    select: onSelect,
                                    loadOnDemand: false,
                                    dataSource: homogeneous,
                                    dataTextField: "ReportGroupName",
                                    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html())
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Comment: try to use hasChildren property?

Comment: I use the hasChildren , but can i use it in the template?

Comment: yes, why not? try it here [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UfUJu)

Comment: Yes I see it working in the dojo,  I guess my data coming from remote source it not structured the same way,  is there a way I can extract the data to place hard coded in-line ?

Comment: I have   under my model:      id: "Id"   , children: "items",    hasChildren: "Id"

Comment: I put more of my code into the question ,  thx in advance

Comment: the way i see it, youre pointing the **hasChildren** to **Id** is wrong. hasChildren suppose to be a true/false value. There is another way to achieve the same result by checking if the **items** is null/not null use **!item.items**

Comment: Ok here is a Fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/MillerDev/8gxms4e2/    word "delete" represents what the end image will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is what you did which cause the mistake

1. Take a look on your **JSON** data, the 1st data which don't have **items**. You should still use add null `items : null`, otherwise it will be another error
2. **hasChildren** should be pointed to **items** not **Id** `hasChildren: "items"`

Here i forked your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/machun/6s0uyguc/2/)